# Using Zend Framework 1 Service Window Azure Standalone

Tags: zend-framework, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using zend service for window azure wrapper class standaline in my custom application. I would like to know how do i connect to my window azure storage. there seems to be no way i can specify the connection details (storage key etc)

```
$storageClient = new Zend_Service_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob();
$result = $storageClient->createContainer('testcontainer');
echo 'Container name is: ' . $result->Name;
```

I am taking refernces from http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.windowsazure.storage.blob.html

zend/Azure expert advice appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code to the IndexController in your application

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if($auth->hasIdentity()) 
    {
        $this->view->content = '<h1>Welcome to TestIndex!</h1>';

        // Need to  change 
    } 
    else 
    {    
        $storageClient = new Zend_Service_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob('blob.core.windows.net', 'YOURNAME', 'YOURCODE');
        $result = $storageClient->createContainer('container');
        echo 'Container name is: ' . $result->Name;
        var_dump($result->Name);
        exit();
    }
}
```